# Navigating from one graph to another in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a day and time chart using react and On clicking the particular day in a week it should take to the corresponding day in time basis.

For example, if I click Wednesday (week chart) it should display the time chart of Wednesday like 12 am to 12 pm.

I have created two different graphs separately and trying to navigate using handle click.

So, the Week graph code is:

```
 <div key={i} className="o-bar" onClick={((e) => this.handleClick(e))}>
<div className="o-bar-inner" tabIndex="0" style={barStyle}  data-tip={customTooltip}></div>
```

and my handleClick funtion where my returning my daily graph is:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("hello")
     if(e.currentTarget){  
      console.log("hello123")
    return (<div><div class="header">Student Reading Activity By Time</div>
    <div id="overview-dialy"></div></div>);
     }
  }
```

The issue is both the consoles are displayed but the graph is not navigating.Is there any solution to fix?

Comment: You should use `handleClick` to set some state that you then can use to determine which graph to show in `render`. What you're returning from `handleClick` is not being used anywhere

Comment: Yeah,I got it.Thanks :)